# How to prevent every time open application while error occurred vb6 dll in process?

Tags: vb6

I made some VB6 COM Dlls reference to my application. When I run my application it's working fine if I give the valid input. When I give some invalid input or randomly some exception is coming. While I getting any error message after that my dll doesn't open. But when I close the application and open again means it will work fine until I get any error message. Can anybody tell how to solve this problem?

Comment: debug and improve your error handling logic

Comment: I've read your question a number of times, and I am having a really hard time understanding what you are asking. How can VB6 COM DLLs reference your application (presumably an EXE)? What do you mean by "after that my dll doesn't open"? Other than that, I can only guess that @rags is correct and you haven't made any attempt to do validation and error handling.

Comment: Sorry for improper post. What i am saying is when my application throw the run time error i can't do anything. But if i closed my app then reopen means it's working fine.But i need to start my work with out close and reopen my application.